# Mail() Not Working inside Function

Tags: php

The function below is not being executed:

```
function sendCode(){
    $our_mail = 'username@gmail.com'
    $to = $email;
    $msg = "Hi $first_name, \n\nYour email has been used to sign up with us. To activate your account \nuse activation code:\n$unique_id\n\nThis message was sent to $email at your request."; 
    $subject = "$unique_id is your account activation code.";
    mail($to,$subject,$msg,'$from:'.$our_mail);
}

if($result){
    header('Location:activate.php'); //redirect
    sendCode();
}
```

while, this is working fine:

```
if($result){
    header('Location:activate.php'); //redirect
    $our_mail = 'username@gmail.com'
    $to = $email;
    $msg = "Hi $first_name, \n\nYour email has been used to sign up with us. To activate your account \nuse activation code:\n$unique_id\n\nThis message was sent to $email at your request."; 
    $subject = "$unique_id is your account activation code.";
    mail($to,$subject,$msg,'$from:'.$our_mail); 
}
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Your code should be triggering several notices. I suggest you enable full error reporting in your development box. That way PHP itself will tell you about missing variables. I know I get ignored almost every time I give this piece of advice but it's still a good tip.

Comment: thanks mate. I have solved the issue this time but it can be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a function variable scope will be local so you need to declare variable as global or pass using parameter. Also do rediretion after send mail

try this:

```
function sendCode($email){
 $our_mail='username@gmail.com'
 $to=$email;
 $msg= "Hi $first_name, \n\nYour email has been used to sign up with us. To activate your account \nuse activation code:\n$unique_id\n\nThis message was sent to $email at your request."; 
 $subject="$unique_id is your account activation code.";
 mail($to,$subject,$msg,'$from:'.$our_mail);
}

if($result){

 sendCode($email);
 header('Location:activate.php'); //redirect
}
```

OR

```
function sendCode(){
    global $email,$unique_id,$first_name; //<----- make variables global
     $our_mail='username@gmail.com'
     $to=$email;
     $msg= "Hi $first_name, \n\nYour email has been used to sign up with us. To activate your account \nuse activation code:\n$unique_id\n\nThis message was sent to $email at your request."; 
     $subject="$unique_id is your account activation code.";
     mail($to,$subject,$msg,'$from:'.$our_mail);
    }

    if($result){

     sendCode();
    header('Location:activate.php'); //redirect

    }
```

Comment: comment `header('Location:activate.php');` then check

Comment: on commenting that line it says $unique_id and $first_name undefined variable even though they are globally defined.

Comment: Where have you defined those variable as global?

Comment: All the variables are defined right after php opening tag like
$unique_id = $first_name = $last_name = $email ="";

Comment: It does not mean its global. You have to define it as global inside function definition using `global` keyword.refer this :  http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: done that. It stills gives same error on commenting that line.

Comment: I used your edited code. I still don't get mail. It's exactly same as your answer.

Comment: I made everything global. I commented that line you asked me to. I still don't get mail. Though I don't get undefined error now.

Comment: if the code without function is working then this also must be working. As only change of global variables. try to do echo in function Are you getting all desired value or not

Comment: Yes on echoing echo $our_mail;
                 echo $email;
                 echo $msg;
                 echo $subject; They hold right values.

Comment: It worked making the values global. Thank you so much. It turned out that while taking your instruction I deleted this line mail($to,$subject,$msg,'$from:'.$our_mail);
now it works. :) Thank you so much.